# DATEDIFF in MySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to calculate difference between two dates in days, here are the two dates:

```
$date_1 = "2017-06-12 13:44:58";
$date_2 = "2017-05-04 19:06:24";
```

When I do it through PHP script it gives 38 as result, which is correct.

```
$datediff = strtotime($date_1) - strtotime($date_2);
echo floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

**Result: 38** ----> **Correct**
**Because there is still difference in hours of the given dates**

But when I do the same in MySQL, then it gives 39 as result, which is wrong.

```
select DATEDIFF("2017-06-12 13:44:58","2017-05-04 19:06:24")
```

**Result: 39** ----> **Incorrect**

Comment: Actual difference in PHP (if you remove the `floor()` function) is `38.776782407407`. If 38 is correct and 39 is not, it's because you have a specific definition you haven't really shared.

Comment: but i need 38 as result, because it will be 39 when both dates will be equal, means, when 2017-06-12 13:44:58 will reach 19:06:24

Comment: Using a more obvious example: how many days are there from yesterday at 0:00:00 and today at 23:59:59? What's your **exact** definition?

Comment: you are not getting my point, but "Michael O." got my point,
look at the given answer, you will get to know what i am asking, 39 is incorrect, because it's 1:44 PM yet, it should show 39 when it reach 7:06 PM.

Comment: why people are down-voting??? Please explain atleast, don't misuse the right given by SO.

Comment: It's not about guessing what you mean. There're many algorithms that will return 38 with that specific data. If you don't set a proper definition you'll pick an arbitrary calculation that will just fail randomly when you deploy to production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MySQL help:

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from
>   one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time
>   expressions. **Only the date parts of the values are used in the
>   calculation**.

You can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` instead:

```
select ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,"2017-06-12 13:44:58","2017-05-04 19:06:24"));
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,"2017-06-12 13:44:58","2017-05-04 19:06:24")) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                  38 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: that's great, can't we remove (-) from result, i mean it would be better if it shows only 38

Comment: Given the specs (or lack of), an alternative query could be `SELECT 38 AS diff`... It works fine for the example given.

Comment: @Santosh thanks for your suggestion, i know i can interchange it, but what Michael suggested is the correct one.

Comment: And if you want a pure PHP version: `function diff ($d1, $d2) { return 38;}`.

Comment: @Álvaro, remarkable, I tried that with `diff(39, 1)` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
SELECT FLOOR(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, "2017-06-12 13:44:58","2017-05-04 19:06:24") / 24));
```

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR...)` will get the difference in hour
so we have to divide it by 24 to get the difference in days.

The `ABS` is to avoid to have a negative number.